Trouble adding data to pyinstaller
I've been trying to add a folder and a .zip file to my .exe I create but either I'm not adding it right, or I can't figure out how to access it once it's added. Here is my Analysis part of my spec file:
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('files', '.'), ('minecraft_world.zip', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)

files is a folder, and minecraft_world.zip is the .zip file. Here is how I'm trying to access a file in files:
subprocess.call("files\\Java.exe", shell=True)
I make the .exe by running:
python3 -m PyInstaller main.spec
I would have used pyinstaller main.spec, but that returned a command not found error. python3 -m pyinstaller main.spec returns no such module pyinstaller
I tried various directories like //, \,  /, but they all said the system couldn't find the specified path. I also tried ./ but it said it couldn't find the command '.'
UPDATE: I tried using os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "files", "Java.exe"), but it still said the system couldn't find the path specified. Here is the path it tried to navigate to:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI37642\files\Java.exe

Please include the relevant error messages in your question. What is the module not found?

@Tzane I added it

I finally got it! Thanks @mehdiahmadi for the link, that solved it! I had to use os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS) instead of os.getwd() + <whatever\path\I\wanted>, and I had to change the datas file in my .spec from     datas=[('files', '.'), ('minecraft_world.zip', '.')], to     datas=[('files/', 'files/'), ('minecraft_world.zip', 'minecraft_world.zip')],
